# RSS feed content overflowing div

Tags: javascript, html, css, rss, rss-reader

I'm trying to format an RSS feed from a blogger site to display on my own personal site. When I try to display the content of an entry, it overflows off of the page.

Here's the code for my controller:

```
                var container = document.getElementById("newsFeed");
                $rootScope.newsEntries = result.feed.entries;
                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    var title = document.createElement("h3");
                    title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
                    var content = document.createElement("div");
                    content.innerHTML = entry.content;
                    content.style.width = "100%";
                    content.style.height = "auto";
                    div.appendChild(title);
                    div.appendChild(content);
                    div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                    container.appendChild(div);
```

the html for this just has a div in it, "newsFeed"

Do I need to manually parse the content or can I format it properly with CSS? I've tried adjusting the div width, setting display to "block" and setting the overflow case, but nothing seems to even change how the text displays.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: Try this: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/857EFK6H5CG7Lplz2DSv?p=preview

Comment: add some classes and css rules

Comment: I'd add `word-wrap: break-word;`, to `#newsFeed`, that should stop the text from overflowing the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh forgot about word wrap. Doing `word-wrap: break-word;` fixed it. Thank you David!